# How do I select a record that has a specific value in an exact position of a field?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

How do I select a record that has a value of 'OE' in position 37 of field DESC?

I can find the needed records by using this statement-

```
select DESC
from   TABLEA
where  DESC like '%OE%'
```

But it will also return records with OE located in other positions within DESC.  This would create incorrect results.

I'm using MS SQL 2005.

Comment: I believe a substring on DESC would do it for you http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: DESC is a horrible column name because it is a reserved word used in an ORDER BY clause.

Answer (score 8):

```
select [DESC]
from   TABLEA
where  substring([desc], 37, 2) = 'OE'
```

[SUBSTRING Function (MSDN Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx).

```
SUBSTRING ( value_expression , start_expression , length_expression )
```

If you want to test out two characters at a certain position within the string, then you can use the `SUBSTRING()` function.

Comment: @mkgiblin Glad to help!  Mark this as the answer if it was your solution. :)